# AVAssetWriter metadata Date issue

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter, phphotolibrary

I have the following code to write the date metadata in AVAssetWriter which is going all wrong in iOS 13. Need to know if this is an iOS 13 bug or I am doing something wrong.

```
     private var metadataItems:[AVMetadataItem]? {

       get {
        let locale = Locale.current
        var metadata:[AVMetadataItem] = []
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        let timezone = TimeZone.current
        let timezoneStr = timezone.abbreviation()

        let creationDateMetaData = AVMutableMetadataItem()
        creationDateMetaData.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace.common
        creationDateMetaData.key = AVMetadataKey.commonKeyCreationDate as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
        creationDateMetaData.locale = locale
        creationDateMetaData.value = String(format:"%04ld-%02ld-%02ld %02ld:%02ld:%02ld %@",year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timezoneStr!) as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol   

         metadata.append(creationDateMetaData)

         return metadata
       }
```

It shows dates like 1 Jan 1970 or sometimes 2 Sept 469231 as creation date in Photo Library when exported to photo library using PHPhotoLibrary. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried the following:

```
 extension Date {

    static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = iso8601DateFormatter()

    fileprivate static func iso8601DateFormatter() -> DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
        return formatter
     }

  // http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/
  // http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns
     public func iso8601() -> String {
        return Date.iso8601DateFormatter().string(from: self)
     }

 }
```

And then simply using:

```
        let creationDateMetaData = AVMutableMetadataItem()
        creationDateMetaData.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace.common
        creationDateMetaData.key = AVMetadataKey.commonKeyCreationDate as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
        creationDateMetaData.value = Date().iso8601() as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
```

But no effect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
    let creationDateMetaData = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    creationDateMetaData.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace.common
    creationDateMetaData.key = AVMetadataKey.commonKeyCreationDate as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
    creationDateMetaData.value = Date().iso8601() as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
```

To

```
    let creationDateMetaData = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    creationDateMetaData.keySpace = .common
    creationDateMetaData.key = AVMetadataKey.commonKeyCreationDate as NSString
    creationDateMetaData.value = Date() as NSDate
```

Comment: Seems to be working prima facie with Photos app on Mac.